# Apple Watch - is there a way to switch location provider from phone to watch?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

As I understand it, when using location services on the Apple Watch it's up to the OS to decide whether to use the watch's GPS or a paired iPhone's GPS to determine the location.

Is there a way of knowing which source is being used currently, or to force the watch to exclusively use one or the other and be able to switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

No, and it's not a GPS position that Core Location delivers to you but a location, that may have come from any source, not necessarily GPS.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up. So there's no way to, say, make your app switch off location services in one device at a given moment to make sure the location is coming from the other device?